# What's meaning of this code in C?

Tags: c, bison

In some Bison code, what does the following line mean?

```
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex();
```

I know `#define` command but I don't understand the whole command.

Comment: Is that `':'` supposed to be at the end of the line?

Comment: I've replaced the `:` with a `;`, but it would be more conventional for there to be no semi-colon either, so when you write: `YYDECL;`, there isn't a stray semi-colon in the pre-processed code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `YY_DECL` will be expanded to

```
extern "C" int yylex();
```

This is actually C++, not C; when you compile this file with a C++ compiler, it declares that the function `yylex` must be compiled with "C linkage", so that C functions can call it without trouble.

If you don't program in C++, this is largely irrelevant to you, but you may encounter similar declarations in C header files for libraries that try to be compatible with C++. C and C++ can be mixed in a single program, but it requires such declarations for function to nicely work together.

There's probably an `#ifdef __cplusplus` around this `#define`; that's a special macro used to indicate compilation by a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex();
```

Define a macro `YY_DECL` standing for the declaration of a function `yylex` that has 'C' linkage inside a C++ program, taking no arguments and returning an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` - a preprocessor directive declaring a new variable for the preprocessor. But you know that.

`YY_DECL` - the name of the variable.

`extern "C"` - tells the compiler that the following code is pure C. There are a lot of differences between C and C++ and one cannot generally mix C and C++ code. If you include this into declaration, it allows you to use C in C++. EDIT: The code actually not need to be pure C, but it will be linked as such. But the most common usage pattern is to make a C code compatible with C++. Thanks @larsmans for the correction.

`int yylex()` - a declaration of a function named `yylex` with undefined number of parameters and return type `int`

So the whole command assigns a C function declaration to a preprocessor variable.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not declare "pure C", it declares C linkage *only*. As far as a C++ compiler is concerned, the body of the function may use arbitrary C++ features.